# Webservice not Parsing Euro and Other Currency Symbols in JSON Request

Tags: php, ios, xcode, json

I am sending json request with following symbols "€","£" and "¥". The service is returning "unable to parse json" error. Any idea how this could be solved?

Comment: Show us how you send the request and how it is processed on the server.

Comment: What data to you receive? What is the code you use to process it?

Comment: @Oswald This is the request I am sending - 

REQUEST={"methodparam":{"currency":"£"},"request":{"api_username":"username","method":"updateUser","api_password":"password"}}

Comment: @Tjoene I receive the following response from server -     
    Code = 400;
    Detail = "Unable to parse JSON in form.request";
    Response = Error;

Comment: Now I know *what* you send and *what* you recieve. I asked *how* you send it and *how* the server processes it. Some source code would be helpful.

Comment: @Oswald Sorry, I dont know how the server processes the request. Its programmed by someone else. However the request gets successful when I send the "$" sign. It only shows the error when I try to send the above mentioned symbols.

Comment: `$` is in the range of ASCII chars, but `€`, `£` and `¥` are not – so it could be a simple encoding problem.

Comment: Are you adding @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"; to your requests "Content-Type"? (that is, telling the server its utf8)

Comment: @DavidH yes, I am adding the same content-type to the request.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. The problem is because of this only. any solution for this?

Comment: And have you made sure your data is actually _encoded_ in UTF-8 as well?

Comment: You should allways use UTF-8 in your PHP. Set "default_encoding" in your php.ini to "utf-8" or you will allways run into problems with special characters.
JSON also per definition MUST be utf-8 encoded.